# class="d-none d-lg-block" in Bootstrap

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, gridview, styles, bootstrap-grid

I'm trying to use **class="d-none d-lg-block"**. But it doesn't work for me.

Below is the code that I'm trying.

Can you please correct me if I'm wrong?

```
<div class="row-content">
        <div>
          <h2>Corporate Leadership</h2>
          <h3>Peter Pan <small>Chief Epicurious Officer</small></h3>
          <p class="d-none d-lg-block" >
            Our CEO, Peter, credits his hardworking East Asian immigrant parents
            who undertook the arduous journey to the shores of America with the
            intention of giving their children the best future. His mother's
            wizardy in the kitchen whipping up the tastiest dishes with whatever
            is available inexpensively at the supermarket, was his first
            inspiration to create the fusion cuisines for which
            <em>The Frying Pan</em> became well known. He brings his zeal for
            fusion cuisines to this restaurant, pioneering cross-cultural
            culinary connections.
          </p>
    <div>
<div>
```

Answer (score -1):

The content displays only on lg. Please add html tag.

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="row-content">
<div>
    <h2>Corporate Leadership</h2>
    <h3>Peter Pan <small>Chief Epicurious Officer</small></h3>
    <p class="d-none d-lg-block">
        Our CEO, Peter, credits his hardworking East Asian immigrant parents
        who undertook the arduous journey to the shores of America with the
        intention of giving their children the best future. His mother's
        wizardy in the kitchen whipping up the tastiest dishes with whatever
        is available inexpensively at the supermarket, was his first
        inspiration to create the fusion cuisines for which
        <em>The Frying Pan</em> became well known. He brings his zeal for
        fusion cuisines to this restaurant, pioneering cross-cultural
        culinary connections.
    </p>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```